# Data Storage and Retrieval in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, hdf5

I have fairly large pandas DataFrames and Panels stored to disk, some are north of 1GB.  I have, in the past, been using .to_pickle and .read_pickle, but typically the saving and retrieval process is >2 minutes.  Is there anyway to speed this up?  I've tried HDF5 storage, and I don't see a significant increase in speed (though I may not be using it correctly).  Are there any libraries/sample code you could point me to which might be helpful?

%time cov_pickle = pd.read_pickle(r'Pickled.p')
Wall time: 1min 29s

%time hd_method = pd.read_hdf(r'Store.h5', 'corr')
Wall time: 1min 32s

Thank you!

Comment: If they are dataframes, have you considered saving them to CSVs?

Comment: many are very large Panel objects, which makes that solution difficult.

Comment: CSV tends to be the faster option. But have you tried JSON or SQL alternatives?

Comment: Trying SQLLite now actually. Thank yoU!